# QueryDSL (Spring+JPA) Limit/Offset when using Transform

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

I am trying to use QueryDSL to transform a Many to Many select into a projection while also applying pagination using JPA.

I have the following entities:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
public class Movie {
   
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_actor",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id"))
    private Set<Actor> actors= new HashSet<>();
}

@Getter @Setter
@Entity
public class Actor {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
}
```

My projections are as follows:

```
@Value
public class SimpleMovieView {
    String title;
    Set<SimpleActorView> actors;
}

@Value
public class SimpleActorView {
    String name;
}
```

My repository is

```
List<SimpleMovieView> all = queryFactory.selectFrom(movie) // JPAQueryFactory
    .leftJoin(movie.stars, actor)
    .transform(groupBy(movie.id).list(constructor(
                                SimpleMovieView.class,
                                movie.title,
                                set(constructor(SimpleActorView.class, actor.name))
)));
```

When you try to apply limit and offset operations I get incorrect results.

I have narrowed down the issue to the JPA query that is being generated, specifically to its results:

Query:

```
select
        m.id,
        m.title,
        a.name 

from movie m

left outer join movie_actor ma
                on m.id=ma.movie_id 

left outer join actor a 
                on ma.actor_id=a.id
```

I believe that due to JPA not aggregating the results (as you would usually do in a GROUP BY or similar manner) the following is fetched

| id | title | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Movie Title 1 | Actor Name 1 |
| 1 | Movie Title 1 | Actor Name 2 |
| 2 | Movie Title 2 | Actor Name 2 |

The issue comes when you try to do a Limit/Offset as it is applied to the above result set.

If you try to limit only 2 entries you should get 2 movies, but since the first two rows are for Movie 1 you will get just a single result.

Is is possible to have this done with QueryDSL and Spring Data JPA (or at all...)

Comment: No, you can't really paginate plural entity joins in any meaningful way with JPA. There is little that Spring or QueryDSL can do about that, as they simply wrap plain JPA. When the result size is limited, filter in Java. When the result size is big, I recommend executing two queries and correlating them in Java. If you do wish an out of the box solution you could however consider Blaze-Persistence Entity Views with a correlation join that is mapped using the subselect fetch strategy.

Comment: Do you know how Spring Data JPA then fetches paginated Entity Relationships then? Do they also perform this in Java memory?